# LDAPS Connection from Local Active Directory Server to External Client

Tags: active-directory, ldap, centos6

I am looking for a solution to my Active Directory problem.

Environment:
Attempting to authenticate users on an external Centos 6.4 website (outside our firewall) by connecting to Microsoft Active Directory which is located behind the firewall.

Currently, we use active directory within our firewall via the domain activedirectory.website.local and works fine. We are in the process of moving some of our sites to an externally hosted server so we need SSL. We have generated a self-signed ssl cert on the active directory server and have exported the ca.pem to the Centos server.

When I try to authenticate Active Directory through the terminal in the client Centos machine (located outside our firewall), I get an error:

> TLS: hostname (firewall.website.com) does not match common name in
>   certificate (activedirectory.website.local)

This error occurs because:

- I am trying to access active directory which is behind our firewall from a client computer from outside
- the certificate says "Hey I'm generated from
  activedirectory.website.local but you are asking for
  firewall.website.com".

We talked to an SSL company about getting a commercial SSL for the .local server and they said they could sell us one for a year. Beyond that year they would not be able to extend the SSL due to some sort of regulation.

Due to the complexity of the network, I cannot change the domain name of activedirectory.website.local or firewall.website.com.

I'm sure someone has ran into this problem but I currently can't find any solutions on the web.

All I need from active directory is usernames and passwords for login authentication.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, (shitty ... *caca boudin* in french) can't you declare `activedirectory.website.local` with the right IP adress in `/etc/hosts`.

Another thing I see is to buy a certificate (or to create your own using your own CA) and install it on the Active-Directory service. Have a look to [How to enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051/en-us).

Comment: I will try to direct the hostname using IP address in hosts file... I will let you know.

Comment: I changed activedirectory.website.local domain in the hosts file to point to the activedirectory.website.local ip address. Does not connect because the firewall is blocking it. Our firewall allows port 636 for LDAPS. So in our case, it seems that we must call the url for the firewall instead of the AD server, bringing me back to the drawing board.

Comment: Okay - that works!!! I had the incorrect server ip address for the AD server in my hosts file. <br />